# Wait until ajax request is completed

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, request, extjs5

I have a form with several comboboxes within a window.

If I display the window and close it immediately (with a button close method), sometimes I have poor connection to the server and the request to load the data in comboboxes is interrupted.

Response is "Failed to load response data".

Sometimes, the same happens when a combobox is expanded and the store has not yet been loaded.

For these cases, in my Application.js file I have the following function which displays an error message.

```
Ext.util.Observable.observe(Ext.data.Connection, {
requestexception: function (connection, response, options) {
      Ext.Ajax.abort(store.operation.request);
        Ext.Msg.show({
            title: 'Error!',
            msg: 'Message...',
            icon: Ext.Msg.ERROR,
            buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
        });
    }
  }
});
```

I'm trying to prevent the window from being closed until the requests were completed and the data was loaded into the comboboxs.

I do not want to use setTimeout().

Maybe use a mask in window and do the unmask when the request is completed ou disabled/enable de close button.

I appreciated suggestions for finding a solution to this.

**EDITED:**

Another possibility, probably simpler, is to iterate through all the combobox of the form and check if, in each combobox, the store.isLoading (): If yes, it displays a message to wait until the load is finished.

**EDITED**

If the form has only one combobox the following handler seems to solve the problem: it creates an initial mask and unmasks it after the store is loaded:

```
handler: function (btn) {
  var win = Ext.widget('winSearch', {
    animateTarget: this
  }).showBy(this, 'bl');

  win.getEl().mask('Loading...');    

  var store =  Ext.getStore('storeCombo1Id');    

  if(store.isLoading()){
     store.on('load', function() {
        win.getEl().unmask();
     });
  }else{
     win.getEl().unmask();
 }
}
```

The problem is to iterate through several combobox: I tried the following code, without success (the stores are in a viewmodel):

```
handler: function (btn) {
  var win = Ext.widget('winSearch', {
      animateTarget: this
  }).showBy(this, 'bl');

  win.getEl().mask('Loading...');


  // var store1 =  Ext.getStore('storeCombo1Id');
  // var store2 =  Ext.getStore('storeCombo2Id');
  // var store3 =  Ext.getStore('storeCombo3Id');
  // var allComboboxStores = [store1, store2, store3];

  var allComboboxStores = ['storeCombo1Id', 'storeCombo2Id', 'storeCombo3Id'];

  Ext.each(allComboboxStores, function(storeId) {
      var store = Ext.getStore(storeId);

      console.log(store); //console show 3 stores

      if(store.isLoading()){
        store.on('load', function() {
            win.getEl().unmask();
        });
      }else{
        win.getEl().unmask();
      }
   });    
}
```

The problem with this solution is that if the store of one of the comboboxs is loaded it triggers the unmask method independently of other comboboxs still to be loaded.

How to wait until all stores are loaded?

**EDITED**

I have tried different types of iterations and loops and the following solution seems to work.

```
handler: function () {
var win = Ext.widget('mywindow', {
    animateTarget: this
}).showBy(this, 'bl');

win.getEl().mask('Loading...');

var allComboboxStores = ['storeCombo1Id', 'storeCombo2Id', 'storeCombo3Id'];

var indexStores = 0;
Ext.each(allComboboxStores, function(storeId) {
    var store = Ext.getStore(storeId);
     if(store){
        if(store.isLoading()){
            indexStores++
            store.on('load', function() {
                indexStores--;
                if (indexStores == 0){
                    win.getEl().unmask();
                }
            });
        }
        else if(!store.isLoading() && indexStores == 0){
             win.getEl().unmask();
        }
    }
 });  
}
```

I appreciated suggestions to improve this solution or suggestions to do otherwise.

Comment: Why dont you use ajax request with async:false.

Comment: Try having a numeric variable in top level "noStoresLoading", which will be incremented ("noStoresLoading++") 

every time when a store is loading data and it will descremented every time when a store is loaded/error ("noStoresLoading--")

At any point of time of "noStoresLoading" == 0 , you know there is no store loading

Comment: @ Tejas1991. Thanks for the suggestion (very interesting). I tested it on my app and it did not solve the problem because the window can be closed while request is taking place (slowly)  which causes an "error": Failed to lod response data

Comment: @Jeba Prince. Thanks for the sugestion. Your idea seems to be a very viable solution. However, in my specific case, I'm having some difficulty in reconciling noStorsLoading ++, noStorsLoading-- and noStorsLoading == 0. Can you please elaborate a bit more so I understand the way forward

Comment: @josei Lets assume you have 3 stores that has to be loaded.

You need to  Show Mask - when stores are loading and Hide mask  - when there are no stores loading.

Have a variable/property "noStoresLoading" (default to 0) in your view or controller.

In all your store when it is loading you will increment (noStoresLoading++).
In all your store when it is loaded/error you will descrement (noStoresLoading--)

In above places check if noStoresLoading == 0 then hide Mask or else show mask if not showing already.

Comment: Use a counter field in the object itself. Initially it has the value of 0. At the end of every load you add 1 to this value until the maxCounter has the value of all your comboboxes. You can set this value to 0 again when you hide the window instead of destroying it. Don't forget to catch the event on the close tool in the upper right corner of the window.

Comment: @Johan thanks. I edited my post with a solution. It probably will not be the best coding, but it seems to work. Any other suggestions to improve the code or to implement another solution will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is not a problem ... I suggest using [Promises](https://api.jquery.com/promise/)

> Description: Return a Promise object to observe when all actions of a certain type bound to the collection, queued or not, have finished.

Comment: Thanks Addy for the sugestion. In this app I have to use extjs or pure javascript

Comment: Extjs has Promises too ... Try the link here : https://www.sencha.com/blog/asynchronous-javascript-promises/

Comment: @Addy Only ExtJS 6, not 5, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I edit my question. I appreciated suggestions for finding a solution.